# Selecting a row from array<struct> based on given condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I've a dataframe with following schema -

```
|-- ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- VALUES: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- _v1: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- _v2: string (nullable = true)
```

VALUES are like -

```
[["ABC","a"],["PQR","c"],["XYZ","b"],["TUV","d"]]
[["PQR","g"]]
[["TUV","f"],["ABC","e"]]
```

I've to select a single struct from this array based on the value of _v1. There is a hierarchy in these values like -

"ABC" -> "XYZ" -> "PQR" -> "TUV"

Now, if "TUV" is present, we will select the row with "TUV" in its _v1. Else we will check for "PQR". If "PQR" is present, take its row. Else check for "XYZ" and so on.

The result df should look like - (which will be StructType now, not Array[Struct])

```
["TUV","d"]
["PQR","g"]
["TUV","f"]
```

Can someone please guide me how can I approach this problem by creating a udf ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the order `"ABC" -> "XYZ" -> "PQR" -> "TUV"` in a list?

Comment: This is not in a list. I just have to follow this order. Check for "TUV", if it exists - take it. Else check for "PQR", if it exists - take it. Else check for "XYZ" and so on. But it can be placed in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def getIndex = udf((array : mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
  if(array.contains("TUV")) array.indexOf("TUV")
  else if(array.contains("PQR")) array.indexOf("PQR")
  else if(array.contains("XYZ")) array.indexOf("XYZ")
  else if(array.contains("ABC")) array.indexOf("ABC")
  else 0
})

df.select($"VALUES"(getIndex($"VALUES._v1")).as("selected"))
```

You should have following output

```
+--------+
|selected|
+--------+
|[TUV,d] |
|[PQR,g] |
|[TUV,f] |
+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

You can select the elements of `struct` column by using `.` notation. Here `$"VALUES._v1"` is selecting all the `_v1` of `struct` and passing them to `udf` function as `Array` in the same order.

for example : for `[["ABC","a"],["PQR","c"],["XYZ","b"],["TUV","d"]]`, `$"VALUES._v1"` would return `["ABC","PQR","XYZ","TUV"]` which is passed to `udf` function

Inside `udf` function, index of array where the strings matched is returned. for example : for ["ABC","PQR","XYZ","TUV"], "TUV" matches so it would return 3.

for the first row, `getIndex($"VALUES._v1")` would return `3` so `$"VALUES"(getIndex($"VALUES._v1")` is equivalent to `$"VALUES"(3)` which is the fourth element of `[["ABC","a"],["PQR","c"],["XYZ","b"],["TUV","d"]]` i.e. `["TUV","d"]` .

I hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. Can you please explain your solution a little but more, specially how you are passing the parameters to the udf and getting the results ?

Comment: explanation is added. :) thanks for the upvote and acceptance

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as each row only contains each `_v1` values at most once. The `UDF` will return the index of the best value in the `hierarchy` list. Then the stuct containing this value in `_v1` will be selected and put into the "select" column.

```
val hierarchy = List("TUV", "PQR", "XYZ", "ABC")

val findIndex = udf((rows: Seq[String]) => {
  val s = rows.toSet
  val best = hierarchy.filter(h => s contains h).head
  rows.indexOf(best)
})

df.withColumn("select", $"VALUES"(findIndex($"VALUES._v2")))
```

A list is used for the order to make it easy to extend to more than 4 values.

Comment: Thanks. Your method worked as expected. But what if I've n number of nested columns in VALUES, not just _v1 and _v2 ?

Comment: @Ishan Didn't realize that was a constraint. Made it possible for there to be more nested values, the hierarchy is extendable to more than 4 values as well.